# Filter a list twice. Which is the most convenient way?

Tags: python

It may be trivial, but I’m not finding a clean solution which would not slow down the code for this.

I will use the array "a" as example.
input

```
a = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,1]]
```

From this array, I would like to get this output
i.e. for each a[:,0] the max[:,1] value.

```
b = [[0,3], [1,2]]
```

A dirty way would be to iterate along a[:,0].

Comment: What do you mean by a[:,0] and max[:,1]?

Comment: That the result should return a unique value for the column 0 bounded with the respective maximum value in the column 1.

Comment: @ImranD It's extended slice syntax. It's available to any type that implements `__getitem__`, but the type has to explicitly define how it is interpreted. `list` doesn't. `a[:,0]` is equivalent to `a.__getitem__((slice(), 0))`.

Comment: A pandas solution might be natural. Grouping and getting group maxes is exactly the sort of thing that pandas is designed for. Something like `df.groupby(0).max()` (once the lists of lists is converted to a dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,1]]

[max(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(a), key=lambda x: x[0])]
# [[0, 3], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: This is probably the most pythonic solution. +1

Comment: This will fail for e.g. `[[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 3]]`. The items should always be sorted first (unless the order is guaranteed).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
a = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,1]]

for x,y in a:
    d[x].append(y)

b = [[x,max(d[x])] for x in d]  #b = [[0,3], [1,2]]
```

Since a dictionary is not an ordered type, the order in which the sublists appear in `b` is not strictly guaranteed (though should be this way in current versions of Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,1]]
b = sorted(a, key=sum, reverse=True)[:2]
print(b) # [[0, 3], [1, 2]]
```

> **Comment:** 
>   For `a = [[0,3],[0,4],[1,1],[1,2]]`, the above code display `[[0, 4], [0, 3]]` instead of `[[0, 4], [1, 2]]`.

So, here is the new version of the code that works perfectly

> **Update:** New version of the code:

```
def filter_list(a):
    return sorted([max(a), max([i for i in a if i[0] != max(a)[0]])])

a = [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,1]]
print(filter_list(a)) # [[0, 3], [1, 2]]

a = [[0,3],[0,4],[1,1],[1,2]]
print(filter_list(a)) # [[0, 4], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: Works in OP's data, but won't work in general. What if `a = [[0,3],[0,4],[1,1],[1,2]]`? The idea is good, but the `key` is problematic.

Comment: You are right. I post my answer before he explains his need in the comment section under his post. I've updated the code.

Comment: Again: does not work in general. What if `a = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,3],[2,1]]`?

Comment: This seems to work, but writing the function as a 1-liner computes `max(a)` multiple times rather than just once and if anything detracts from readability.

Comment: @JohnColeman It doesn't really work: it will only ever find two values.

Comment: @ekhumoro OP specifies a scenario where there are just two of what they are calling columns. For that situation, the code should work, but it doesn't generalize very nicely to multiple columns (such as the 3 in your case).

Comment: @ekhumoro: the code will display `[[1, 2], [2, 3]]` for `a = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2],[1,1],[2,3],[2,1]]`.

Comment: @codrelphi The correct result is `[[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 3]]`.

Comment: @JohnColeman The OP specifies: "for each a[:,0] the max[:,1] value". There is no limit on the range of `a[0]` values.

Comment: @ekhumoro I see what you mean now. I didn't read OP correctly at first. I initially thought of "twice" as referring to once for `0` and once for `1`, but by twice they mean once to get the distinct elements in the first column (which may number more than 2) and once to get the corresponding maxes in the second column. I agree that the code in this answer doesn't work. It could be fixed by successive filtering in a loop, but then would become quite inefficient.